# How to perform an "I can reach my database" healthcheck?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a classic spray+slick http server which is my database access layer, and I'd like to be able to have an healthcheck route to ensure my server is still able to reach my DB.

I could do it by doing a generic sql query, but I was wondering if there was a better way to just check the connection is alive and usable without actually adding load on the database (or at least the minimum possible load).

So pretty much :

`val db = Database.forConfig("app.mydb")
[...]
db.???? // Do the check here`

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to avoid executing a query against the database?

I think the best health check is to actually use the database as your application would (actually connecting and running a query). With that in mind, you can perform a `SELECT 1` against your DB, and verify that it responds accordingly.

Comment: Well, it seemed like an overhead to me to execute a query with no interest in the result. And it will slightly skew some of my db metrics for monitoring purposes. But I may end up doing that.

Comment: most jdbc4 drivers support isValid() method on connection objects. You'll have to check the driver documentation if the method is implemented